# Contour plot using bplot function in rms package

Tags: r, ggplot2, contour, rms

I have been trying to make a contour plot for prediction models with R, based on the bplot function in "rms" package. The codes are as follows:

```
library(rms)
n <- 1000
set.seed(17)
age <- rnorm(n, 50, 10)
blood.pressure <- rnorm(n, 120, 15)
cholesterol <- rnorm(n, 200, 25)
sex <- factor(sample(c('female','male'), n,TRUE))
L <- .4*(sex=='male') + .045*(age-50) + (log(cholesterol - 10)-5.2)*(-2*(sex=='female') + 2*(sex=='male'))
y <- ifelse(runif(n) < plogis(L), 1, 0)
ddist <- datadist(age, blood.pressure, cholesterol, sex)
options(datadist='ddist')
fit <- lrm(y ~ blood.pressure + sex * (age + rcs(cholesterol,4)), x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
p <- Predict(fit, age, cholesterol, sex, np=50)
bplot(p,, contourplot, region = TRUE,col.regions=topo.colors)
```

And I noticed that the output figure was like this:

[image]

I couldn't find out how to smoothen the zigzag borderlines between two filled regions, so I wonder if this kind of contour plot for prediction models could be made with ggplot2 or if there are any other solutions to smoothen the zigzag borderlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can plot similar plot with combination of `geom_tile` and `geom_contour`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(p), aes(age, cholesterol, fill = yhat, z = yhat)) +
    geom_tile() +
    geom_contour(color = "black") +
    scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral", limits = c(-2, 2)) +
    labs(x = "Age",
         y = expression(Total~Cholesterol["mg/dl"]),
         fill = NULL) +
    facet_grid(~ sex) +
    theme_classic()
```

[image]

Edit: As OP requested I added discrete colors:

```
ggplot(data.frame(p), aes(age, cholesterol, z = yhat)) +
    geom_tile(aes(fill = factor(round(yhat)))) +
    geom_contour(color = "black") +
    labs(x = "Age",
         y = expression(Total~Cholesterol["mg/dl"]),
         fill = NULL) +
    facet_grid(~ sex) +
    theme_classic()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This figure looks much better than mine! 
Is there any method that can fill the regions between 2 contour lines with only one color instead of gradient color in this figure? 
For example, is it possible to fill in the region between 0 and 0.5 with green and that between 0.5 and 1 with yellow?

Comment: @HansWang I added solution, however it gives pixeled figure (it's not probably what you want to do; don't know if that's even possible). Please let me know if it works/how can I improve my answer.

Comment: Thanks again! I tried this new code, and similarly I got pixeled figure. I thought this might be related to the number of cases in the data frame (perhaps the size of the pixels are decided by the number of cases), and I created a data set with 5000 thousand cases instead of the original 1000, but still it didn't help.

Comment: @HansWang It's just not possible - either you: 1. Have continuous color/fill scale; 2. Have discrete scale, but pixeled; 3. Have discrete scale, but step-line contour line (actually I don't know you to draw such line).

Comment: Thanks, it's probably just a disadvantage of rms package, I'll try some other packages.